# составить метод update

Tags: php, sql, ооп, строки, pdo

Хочу с помощью строковых операторов создать sql запрос `update`. Есть рабочий пример с `insert`. Данные поступают из $_POST, например:

```
$array = $_POST["pet"] = "cat";
```

где ключи равны именам столбца таблицы, а значение будет попадать в БД, как значение:

```
   $sql  = "UPDATE ". $nameTable ." SET";

   // implode keys of $array...
   $sql .= " (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($array))."`)";

   // implode values of $array...
   $sql .= " VALUES ('".implode("', '", $array)."') ";

   $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute();
```

Рабочий пример с `insert into`:

```
   class SqlQuery
   {

    public function InsertText($array, $nameTable)
    {
    // build query...
   $sql  = "INSERT INTO ". $nameTable;

   // implode keys of $array...
   $sql .= " (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($array))."`)";

   // implode values of $array...
   $sql .= " VALUES ('".implode("', '", $array)."') ";

   $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute();

   $e = DB::lastInsertId();

   return $e;
    }

    public function UpdateText($array, $nameTable)
    {
    // build query...


   $sql  = "UPDATE ". $nameTable ." SET";

   // implode keys of $array...
   $sql .= " (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($array))."`)";

   // implode values of $array...
   $sql .= " VALUES ('".implode("', '", $array)."') ";

   $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute();

   $e = DB::lastInsertId();

   return $e;
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно пренебрегать подготовленными выражениями:

```
protected function buildUpdate($table, $data) {
  $fields = [];
  foreach ($data as $k => $v) $fields[] = "{$k} = ?"; // Данные никогда не должны становиться частью запроса
  $fields = implode(', ', $fields);

  // Для "минималистов"
  // $fields = implode(',', array_reduce(array_keys($data), function($key) { return "$key = ?"; }, []))

  return "UPDATE $table SET $fields";
}
public function update($table, $data) {
  $sql = $this->buildInsert($table, $data);
  return $this->exec($sql, array_values($data)); // Метод exec выполняет подготовленный запрос, используя переданные данные (с вашим любимым драйвером БД)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Сделал. Чуть позже полностью класс выложу.

```
$array = $_POST;

$arrVal = $array;

$arrKey = array_keys($array);


$all = [];

foreach ($arrKey as $key => $val) {
  $all[] = "`".$arrKey[$key]."` = '".$arrVal[$val]."'";
}

$allStrong = implode(",", $all);
```

Comment: У вас sql-инъекция отклеилась